# How can I make an image appear over the filled areas of another image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UIImageView that contains an image that has a transparent area around itself. I would like an image to appear on top of this UIImageView that is only visible within the nontransparent portion. How is this possible on iOS? I assume quartzcore would help here, but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Code examples/explanation would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
```

May this will be help full